# QISKIT Metal Saves Error Generating Python Code

Tags: qiskit, programming

## Background

I'm testing out the ability of the Metal GUI to save a simple circuit but it keeps generating code that gives rise to various errors. In the below code for example generates an error show below the code. I'm running this in Jupyter Notebooks.

#### Code

```
Readout_1 = RoutePathfinder(
design,
name='Readout_1',
options={'_actual_length': '4.018685284646162 '
                   'mm',
 'anchors': {0: array([ 1.65, -0.8 ])},
 'fillet': '90um',
 'hfss_wire_bonds': True,
 'lead': {'end_jogged_extension': '',
          'end_straight': '200um',
          'start_jogged_extension': '',
          'start_straight': '200um'},
 'pin_inputs': {'end_pin': {'component': 'Cap_Readout_1',
                            'pin': 'north_end'},
                'start_pin': {'component': 'Q_1',
                              'pin': 'B3'}},
 'trace_gap': 'cpw_gap'},

type='CPW',
)
```

#### Error

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 6
1 Readout_1 = RoutePathfinder(
2 design,
3 name='Readout_1',
4 options={'_actual_length': '4.018685284646162 '
5                    'mm',
----> 6  'anchors': {0: array([ 1.65, -0.8 ])},
7  'fillet': '90um',
8  'hfss_wire_bonds': True,
9  'lead': {'end_jogged_extension': '',
10           'end_straight': '200um',
11           'start_jogged_extension': '',
12           'start_straight': '200um'},
13  'pin_inputs': {'end_pin': {'component': 'Cap_Readout_1',
14                             'pin': 'north_end'},
15                 'start_pin': {'component': 'Q_1',
16                               'pin': 'B3'}},
17  'trace_gap': 'cpw_gap'},
18
19 type='CPW',
20 )

TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list

## Question

How can I fix this error? Is there a missing important statement or do I need to change the generated/saved code?